# How to get event of card scratching completed in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, scratchcard

I got few scratch card examples form github . All are working fine, but the thing which is missing in them is the event when I have scratched the gray surface and the gift/prize is visible. If user is scratching and the scratching reached a certain percentage i.e. 70% or 80% I want to fire event and perform further functionality.

I have done research on google, but so far no results. Also I am new to iOS development.

links of project I took

[Scratch Card View](https://github.com/HarveyHu/HHScratchCardViewSample)

[Scratch-n-See](https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Scratch-n-See you have:

```
- (void)imageMaskView:(ImageMaskView *)maskView cleatPercentWasChanged:(float)clearPercent {
        NSLog(@"percent: %.2f", clearPercent);
}
```

You can't do anything with that? :)

```
if (clearPercent > x)
{
//your code
}
```